# Read tab separated content line by line with last column empty string

Tags: c, fileparsing

I have a file format like this

```
1.9969199999999998  2.4613199999999997  130.81278270000001  AA
2.4613199999999997  2.5541999999999998  138.59131554109211  BB
2.5541999999999998  2.9953799999999995  146.83238401449094  CC
...........................
```

I have to read first three columns as `float` and the last column as `char` array in `C`. All the columns are tab separated and the there is an new line character at the end of each line. Everything works fine with `fscanf(fp1, "%f\t%f\t%f\t%s\n", ...)` till I have a some text at the end of each line (the char string part).

There are cases where instead of AA/BB/CC, I have an empty string in the file. How to handle that case. I have tried `fscanf(fp1, "%f\t%f\t%f\t%s[^\n]\n", ...)` and many other things, but I am unable to figure out the right way. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: Don't say "Doesn't work", it's really, *really* irritating. Instead say what it *does* do that you don't want it to, or more specifically, what it isn't doing that you *do* want it to.

Comment: Using `float` rather than `double` will throw away half the digits shown.  You get 6-7 decimal digits with `float`; you get 15+ digits with `double`.

Comment: As to your main question: use `fgets()` to read lines and then `sscanf()` to parse the line that is read.  This will avoid confusion.  When the input is line-based but not regular enough, don't use `fscanf()` and family to read the data — they file-reading `scanf()` functions don't care about newlines, even when you do.  (Note that `sscanf()` will return either 3 or 4, indicating whether there was a string at the end of a line or not.  Always test the return value from `scanf()` and friends — but do so carefully.)

Comment: Me, I would not use any of the *scanf family to solve this sort of problem.  I would read whole lines using `fgets`, then split each line up into tab-separated fields.  Splitting up a line into fields (based on delimiter(s)) is straightforward -- you can use `strtok` or `strsep` for this.  (Or see https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html .)

Comment: @tadman Sorry for the wrong choice of words. Edited the question! Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the help. It worked for me. If you can put it as an answer, I can mark it as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `float` rather than `double` will throw away about half the digits shown. You get 6-7 decimal digits with `float`; you get 15+ digits with `double`.

As to your main question: use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) (or POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) to read lines and then [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) to parse the line that is read. This will avoid confusion.  When the input is line-based but not regular enough, don't use `fscanf()` and family to read the data — the file-reading `scanf()` functions don't care about newlines, even when you do.

Note that `sscanf()` will return either 3 or 4, indicating whether there was a string at the end of a line or not (or `EOF`, `0`, `1` or `2` if it is given an empty string, or a string which doesn't start with a number, or a string which only contains one or two numbers). Always test the return value from `scanf()` and friends — but do so carefully.  Look for the number of values that you expect (3 or 4 in this example), rather than 'not EOF'.

This leads to roughly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double d[3];
    char text[20];
    char line[4096];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        int rc = sscanf(line, "%lf %lf %lf %19s", &d[0], &d[1], &d[2], &text[0]);
        if (rc == 4)
            printf("%13.6f  %13.6f  %13.6f  [%s]\n", d[0], d[1], d[2], text);
        else if (rc == 3)
            printf("%13.6f  %13.6f  %13.6f  -NA-\n", d[0], d[1], d[2]);
        else
            printf("Format error: return code %d\n", rc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If given this file as standard input:

```
1.9969199999999998  2.4613199999999997  130.81278270000001  AA
2.4613199999999997  2.5541999999999998  138.59131554109211  BB
2.5541999999999998  2.9953799999999995  146.83238401449094  CC
19.20212223242525  29.3031323334353637 3940.41424344454647
19.20212223242525  29.3031323334353637 3940.41424344454647  PolyVinyl-PolySaccharide
```

the output is:

```
 1.996920       2.461320     130.812783  [AA]
 2.461320       2.554200     138.591316  [BB]
 2.554200       2.995380     146.832384  [CC]
19.202122      29.303132    3940.414243  -NA-
19.202122      29.303132    3940.414243  [PolyVinyl-PolySacch]
```

You can tweak the output format to suit yourself.  Note that the `%19s` avoids buffer overflow even when the text is longer than 19 characters.

Comment: Very well explained.. Thank you!